# CMU Sphinx and time indexed words

Tags: speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I have run the example of Pocketsphinx Python and now I am facing the issue that I want to run a 60sec wav file for speech recognition in English and want as output 
- the English translation AND 
- at which second each word was mentioned.

Now, I do not know where to start to dome some research to get the required output. Could anyone please point me in the right direction??

Answer (score 0):

ok, the open source tools like Kaldi automatically offers this:
https://americanarchivepb.wordpress.com/2017/12/04/dockerized-kaldi-speech-to-text-tool/

Comment: The question is about pocketsphinx, not Kaldi.

Answer (score 0):

You need recognition with [forced alignment](http://www.voxforge.org/home/docs/faq/faq/what-is-forced-alignment). Here is an [example](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/pocketsphinx_pronunciation_evaluation/) for pocketsphinx:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous
    -infile with.wav
    -jsgf with-word.jsgf
    -dict words.dict
    -backtrace yes
    -fsgusefiller no
    -bestpath no 
  2>&1 > with-word.txt
```

Output:

```
==> with-word.txt <==
INFO: fsg_search.c(869): fsg 0.05 CPU 0.051 xRT
INFO: fsg_search.c(871): fsg 0.09 wall 0.084 xRT
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(1171): sil with sil (-2607)
word                 start end   pprob ascr       lscr       lback
sil                  3     77    1.000 -1602      0          1
with                 78    102   1.000 -845       0          1
sil                  103   107   1.000 -160       0          1
INFO: fsg_search.c(265): TOTAL fsg 0.05 CPU 0.051 xRT
INFO: fsg_search.c(268): TOTAL fsg 0.09 wall 0.085 xRT
sil with sil
```

For CMU Sphinx 4 you need the `SpeechAligner` class from Sphinx API. [Here](https://github.com/JoshData/cmusphinx-alignment-example) you'll find an implementation of simple aligner tool.

```
./align.sh sample.wav sample.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Output:

```
"it's","IH T S","false","0.0","170","200"
"a","AH","false","-5540774.0","200","390"
"crowd","K R AW D","false","-1.13934288E8","850","1300"
"in","IH N","false","-1.95127088E8","1300","1470"
"two","T UW","false","-2.23176048E8","1470","1700"
"distinct","D IH S T IH NG K T","false","-2.6345264E8","1700","2230"
"ways","W EY Z","false","-3.58427808E8","2230","2730"
"the","DH AH","false","-4.72551168E8","2920","3100"
"fruit","F R UW T","false","-5.24233504E8","3220","3530"
"of","AH V","false","-5.79971456E8","3530","3640"
"a","AH","false","-5.99515456E8","3640","3760"
"figg","F IH G","false","-6.2017152E8","3760","4060"
"tree","T R IY","false","-6.72126656E8","4060","4490"
"is","IH Z","false","-7.4763744E8","4490","4570"
"apple","AE P AH L","false","-7.73581184E8","4630","5040"
"shaped","SH EY P T","false","-8.44424704E8","5040","5340"
```